# How to trap message between two servers?

Tags: tcp, network-access, tcpdump, tap

I have two server one of them sends message in xml format to another server. The number of message varies i.e from 10000/sec to 1 million per second. The other end receives and stores it as file. Both of them are in same network.

I found that some of the files are missing and in log from sending server I got that the message is sent. How do I check if it is lost in network? I cannot track it down in receiving end as it's old application.

Should I use ntop like solution to track down traffic? Any other solution to track message to specific port and visualize it?

[image]

Comment: Whole files don't get lost in the network. You may lose some packets, but depending on the transport protocol used, that probably won't be a problem. You should edit your question to provide a network diagram and the network device configurations. Questions about servers, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off topic.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there any tool like wireshark that can mirror application level communication.

Comment: As @RonMaupin indicated, questions about protocols above OSI layer 4, as application messages are, are off topic here. So are product recommendations.